# Finding sourcegenerated files

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2022, code-generation

I am using VS 17.8.0 Preview 7.0. And I get two errors while compiling the source generated from a razor file. But I can't find the `*.g.cs` files at all. They should be in the obj folder as far as I know, but there is only one I can find.

According to procmon, they are never accessed at all...
[image]
But still they have some errors (but that's an other topic):
[image]
Where are they?